# Linking an appended title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, append

I currently have an editor that allows users to save their edits, by using localstorage and a prompt that asks them for the title of their edit. I've appended the title to a table where they can access it.

Simply put, if they save the edit as "Topic 1", the word "Topic 1" will show up at the side of the webpage. Now I'm wondering, how can I link this "Topic 1" to their edits? Such that when they click it, the editor will show their edits and allow them to edit it again?

```
    <!-- Function to save the user's input inside editor1 -->
    function saveEdits() {
        var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
        var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
        localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
        var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
        localStorage.title = title; 
        document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("Contentable");
        var content = document.createTextNode(title);
        theDiv.appendChild(content);
    }

<!-- Function to check if the user has any saved input -->
    function checkEdits() {
        if(localStorage.userEdits != null)
        document.getElementById("editor1").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this using an onclick function on your editor1 element

```
var editElem =  document.getElementById("editor1");
editElem.innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
editElem.onclick = function() {
         /**Redirect them to the page where their edit is
            If the edit is in the form of an html form
            display it as follows**/
        document.getElementById("your form id").style.display="block";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is currently written, there will only ever be one saved document (`localStorage.userEdits`), so therefore no way to link a title against a document. You need to change your storage structure. Consider something like the following:

```
<!-- Function to save the user's input inside editor1 -->
function saveEdits() {
    var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
    //get the title from user
    var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
    localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.innerHTML); //save the editor contents to local storage based on title
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
    //save the all titles in array so you know what documents exist
    var titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");
    if(titles == null) //no titles saved
        titles = new Array();
    if(titles.indexOf(title) < 0) //if the title is not already saved
        titles.push(title); //add it to array
    localStorage.setItem("titles", titles); //save the titles array to localStorage
    ...
}
```

The code above will allow you to save multiple documents by storing them in local storage based on title, then storing an array of titles into local storage. To load the edits for a given title use the following:

```
<!-- Function to load user's input for given title -->
function loadEdits(title) {
    //load useredit for title from local storage
    var userEdits = localStorage.getItem(title);
    var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
    editElem.innerHTML = userEdits;
}
```

Comment: I've added in the array code, but an error shows up: Uncaught TypeError: titles.push is not a function

Comment: Did you get the portion above the push which checks if `titles == null` and if so creates a new array?

Comment: Yes, it's in my code. I've checked several times - it isn't an issue with the copying and pasting.